# Enum class square brackets

Tags: c#, enums

Why some values are in square brackets and what means 1<<1:

```
public enum PrivilegeFlags : int
{
    None = 0,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Agent")]
    Agent = 1 << 0,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Campaign")]
    Campaign = 1 << 1,
   [EnumMember(Value = "BlackList")]
    BlackList= 1 << 2,
All = (1 << 3) - 1
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Second question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493517/what-do-two-left-angle-brackets-mean-in-c

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets mean that it's an [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), in this case specifically the `EnumMemberAttribute`. Also, [<<](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx) represents a left shift.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the `Enum` is meant to create flags. You can see it more clearly if you translate the enum value into binary:

```
public enum PrivilegeFlags : int
{
    None = 0, //0000 0000
    [EnumMember(Value = "Agent")]
    Agent = 1 << 0, //0000 0001
    [EnumMember(Value = "Campaign")]
    Campaign = 1 << 1, //0000 0010
    [EnumMember(Value = "BlackList")]
    BlackList= 1 << 2, //0000 0100
    All = (1 << 3) - 1 //0000 0111
}
```

and `EnumMember` is an attribute assigned to the `PrivilegeFlags` `enum` members.

You do not need to declare the `enum` as shown as the following is equivalent enum:

```
public enum PrivilegeFlags : int
{
    None = 0, //0000 0000
    [EnumMember(Value = "Agent")]
    Agent = 1, //0000 0001
    [EnumMember(Value = "Campaign")]
    Campaign = 2, //0000 0010
    [EnumMember(Value = "BlackList")]
    BlackList= 4, //0000 0100
    All = 7 //0000 0111
}
```

`1 << 1` means you have value of `1`, and you do binary left-shift of `1` to the value of `1`. It is clearly seen in the binary level:

```
0000 0001 //1 in binary
--------- << 1 shift left by 1
0000 0010 //note the binary shift, now this is actually 2
```

The benefit of using the specified left-shift `<<` is to make the flag creation having incremental number: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...` etc instead of having number in the pattern of `2^n` and `0`: `0, 1, 2, 4, 8, ...`